# Align UV island

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

How do you align UV islands, not all vertices together on same axis, but the whole island?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's not clear to me.. in the screenshots don't you align the 2 islands?

Comment: yes - but manually - this is final output i want to achieve, but that is not how align y works for me. One time it was working, but now it aligns vertices on the axis. I dont know why.